# How can I remove unwanted word on my WP site?

Tags: wp-admin

As this post will likely show, I am new at working with WordPress.  My church website is built in WP. Recently I noticed that there is the word, "Array" that appears in the left upper portion of each web page just below the main banner.  This seems to be a recent occurrence. 
I believe that this is the area where at one time there was an automatically updated date and time display.

Here is the url for the site:  http://lccut.org

How do I remove this?  Thank you in advance for your assistance.
John

Comment: Since we only see the _processed code_, we unfortunately can not help you with just this information. Do you have access to the theme files? Or do you only manage the contents? We need to have a look at the sources. The word _Array_ is printed in a paragraph with the _footer_ class. BTW, the overall layout of the website seems a little odd to me, so I cannot say for sure whre you would find it. _Normally_ it should be placed inside `footer.php`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to open your header.php file and search in that file for this

```
 <p class="footer"> some php will be here </p>
```

You can delete that entire line or comment it out. You should be able to access the header.php file from the backend of WordPress. If you are not comfortable doing this, open the header.php file. Copy all the text in that file and paste it here in your question above by editing the question and someone will show you what to remove.

Just login to your church site. Under the appearance tab, you will see an option that says "Editor". Choose that and then look at the list of files that will be on the right. Look for header.php and copy that code here.